# Programatically insert ActiveX Control into Word Document using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

is it possible? I couldn't find any code that does that.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to write a macro (=VBA) in Office, I just start by recording a macro, and then do what you want to do manually.

The recorded macro will help you on your way.

This is what I ended up with:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="WordPad.Document.1", _
        FileName:="", LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

Answer is: use the [AddOLEObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shapes.addoleobject(VS.80).aspx) method